# what is python equivalent of getInputStream() and getOutputStream()?

Tags: java, python, sockets

I have code written in Java, as I don't know java wanted to establish a socket connection using python but I'm unable to understand what is python equivalent of Java getInputStream() and getOutputStream() ? And how can we use it in python ? Following, you can find the code I already wrote in python.

```
  import socket
    try:
        resMsg = None
        myClient = None
        myClient = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        ip = socket.gethostbyname("usddcwvtrkjxts3")
        #print(ip)
        port = 3450

        address = (ip, port)
        myClient.connect(address)
        data = myClient.recv(1024)
        print(data)
    except:
        print("connection failed")
```

I have following code already written in Java:

```
        public String invoke(String requestMsg) {
            String resMsg = null;
            Socket myClient = null;
            DataInputStream input = null;
            PrintWriter output = null;
            try {
                try {
                    myClient = new Socket("vwddtrkjxts002", 3450);
                    input = new DataInputStream(myClient.getInputStream());
                    output = new java.io.PrintWriter(myClient.getOutputStream(), true);
                    output.println(requestMsg);
                    output.write("\u001A");
                    output.flush();
                    StringBuffer message = new StringBuffer();
                    try {
                        while (true) {
                            message.append((char) input.readByte());
                        }
                    } catch (EOFException e1) {
                    }

                    resMsg = message.toString();
                    System.out.println(resMsg);
                } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                try {
                    output.close();
                    input.close();
                    myClient.close();

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    System.out.println(e);
                }
            }
            return resMsg;
        }
```

I'm able to establish a connection with python but unable to print anything as output.

Any suggestion will help ! Thank you in advance

Comment: To send data to the socket peer, use [`send()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.send) or [`sendall()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.sendall). To receive data from the peer use [`recv()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.recv).

Answer (score 1):

I think `listen()` function is what you need.

Sample code:

```
import socket

HOST = '127.0.0.1'  # Standard loopback interface address (localhost)
PORT = 65432        # Port to listen on (non-privileged ports are > 1023)

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.bind((HOST, PORT))
    s.listen()
```

**This is how python socket work:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can check a good tutorial [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/socket-programming-python/)

In summary,

- as client you initiate the connection, once established, you can use the socket object's recv() and send() methods to receive and send information
- as server you bind to the port and start listening. Once the accept() method returns you have object on which you can call recv and send methods similar to client